# Coriolis force decomposition of angular velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, vectors, angular-velocity, coriolis-effect

I can’t for the life of me understand how the $\omega$ in this is decomposed to

$$\vec{\omega}= \omega (-\sin(\theta),0, \cos(\theta))$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your are asking about the geometry of the problem.

The following picture is a 3D view. The dashed rectangle is the plane-of-interest. The directions are those as experienced by the person.

[image]

The next picture focuses on the plane-of-interest. You can easily see that $\hat{z}$ component (up) is related to $cos\theta$ and North ($-\hat{x}$) is related to $sin\theta$ 
 (hence South is related to $-sin\theta$).

[image]

Finally, the person is glancing towards the west, along the appropriate latitude line. The latitude line is perpendicular to the axis of rotation hence this component (east or west) is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Well. Let a random point on the sphere be $P(x,y,z)$ and Origin be O(0,0,0). If $\theta$ is the angle OP makes with z-axis and $\phi$ be the angle OP makes with x-axis, then

$$P(x,y,z) = (R\sin\theta\cos\phi, R\sin\theta\sin\phi, R\cos\phi)$$

Thus the unit vectors $\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}$ can be written as,

$$\begin{align}\hat{z} &= (\sin\theta\cos\phi) \hat{i} + (\sin\theta\sin\phi) \hat{j} + (\cos\theta) \hat{k}
\\ \hat{y} &= (\sin\phi)\hat{i} + (-\cos\phi)\hat{i}
\\ \hat{x} &= \hat{y} \times \hat{z} = (-\cos\theta\cos\phi)\hat{i}+(-\cos\theta\sin\phi)\hat{i}+(\sin\theta\sin^2\phi+\sin\theta\cos^2\phi)\hat{k}
\end{align}$$

From these three equations we can easily write,

$$\hat{k} = (-\sin\theta) \hat{x} + (\cos\theta)\hat{z}$$

Thus,

$$\omega \hat{k} = (-\omega\sin\theta) \hat{x} + (\omega\cos\theta)\hat{z}$$

i.e.,

$$\vec{\omega}=\omega(-\sin\theta,0,\cos\theta)$$

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the components of the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$, you have to 
calculate first the rotation matrix $R$ between body fixed coordinate system and inertial system
\begin{align*}
&R=\left[\vec{\hat x}\,,\vec{\hat y}\,,\vec{\hat z}\right]\quad,R^T\,R=I_3\\
&\text{with:}\\
\vec{\hat z}&=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left(
\varphi  \right) \\ \sin \left( \vartheta  \right)
\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\ \cos \left(
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right]\\
\vec{\hat y}&=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} \sin \left( \varphi  \right)
\\ -\cos \left( \varphi  \right)
\\ 0\end {array} \right
]\quad,\vec{\hat y}\perp \vec{\hat{z}}\\
\vec{\hat{x}}&=\vec{\hat{y}}\times \vec{\hat{z}}=
\left[ \begin {array}{c} -\cos \left( \vartheta  \right) \cos \left(
\varphi  \right) \\ -\cos \left( \vartheta  \right)
\sin \left( \varphi  \right) \\ \sin \left(
\vartheta  \right) \end {array} \right]
\end{align*}
The components of the angular velocity vector $\vec{\omega}$ can calculate from this equation:
\begin{align*}
 &\left[\frac{d}{dt}\,R\right]=R\,\tilde{\vec{\omega}}\qquad\Rightarrow\quad
 \tilde{\vec{\omega}}=R^T \left[\frac{d}{dt}\,R\right]&(1)\\
 &\tilde{\vec{\omega}}=\begin{bmatrix}
              0 & -\omega_z & \omega_y \\
              \omega_z& 0 & -\omega_x \\
              -\omega_y & \omega_x & 0 \\
            \end{bmatrix}\\\\
 &\text{with equation (1) and the rotation matrix $R$ we get:}\\\\
 &\vec{\omega}=
 \left[ \begin {array}{cc} -\sin \left( \vartheta  \right) &0
\\ 0&1\\ \cos \left( \vartheta
 \right) &0\end {array} \right]
\begin{bmatrix}
  \dot{\varphi} \\
  \dot{\vartheta} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}